# Forcing a window to be "always on top"

Tags: xubuntu, window-manager, system-settings, focus, qbittorrent

Working QBitTorrent in Ubuntu.

QBitTorrent can be fully minimised any of all of the time (not the headless/web interface, the normal Gui interface), but i want it so that it remains open at all times.  I use workspaces, but whenever i switch to the workspace with QBitTorrent in it, it's always minimised and i find no method that seems to force it to remain open.  Plenty of varying options to close it for a plethora of reasons, just never always on top, or just always always open.

I'm guessing the lack of settings within QBitTorrent means it's something to do within Ubuntu (16.04.1 LTS).  Can anyone help me, AskUbuntu is my last chance.  It's needed because when i do need to view information and move categories around i find it crashes very easily, which I'm sure Is related to bringing QBitTorrent into focus as that's when it always crashes, without fail.

Oh give mind, please wish for me today, thanks.

I'll guess it's either something embarrassing easy, or something impossible making major changes to something which makes the system a little unstable

However, this is the best give mind in the internet which is why i came here

Cheers people

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer, while moving things around the difference i noticed that only a few Windows actually let you set the, *always on top* , it has to be s non full screen window.  So the problem is given by making the window small again, then slowly move each side to the edges and top and bottom as far as it will go without actually maximising that window, then you can force an always on top, when u leave that page to go to another session window, the go back and it has remained open and in the screen fixing my original problem.

Even though no one did, thanks for the help and other suggestions. I enjoyed trying them all until i accidentally found this sort method which kinda bypassed one of the true trucking it to be fun screen when it isn't.